# JS : regex pattern "? OR end of string"

Tags: javascript, regex

The strings are of two different types, I have a solution for each of them but I'm looking for a combined solution. For both I need the id '28ae569'.

- type A :

  s='http://www.example.com/en/product/test-427/test-443/test-2289261/a-b-c-28ae569?param1=category~%5b715507%7c208524%5d&bi=1&ps=200'

Solved using : `/.*\/.*-(.*)\?/`

- type B :

  s='http://www.example.com/en/product/test-427/test-443/test-2289261/a-b-c-d-e-f-28ae569

Solved using : `/.*\/.*-(.*)$/`

So what I'm trying to tell the regex is '**? OR end of string**'.

I've tried using ' `\?|$` 'but it did not work, it gives me the whole '28ae569?param1=category~%5b715507%7c208524%5d&bi=1&ps=200' in the first case. I also tried a number of other combinations, but I'm now shooting arrows in the dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match consecutive digits followed by `?` or `$`, whichever comes first in the input string, as group 1.

```
/([a-fA-F0-9]+)(?:\?|$)/
```

Comment: accepted, thanks to both of you guys for making me learn about non capturing groups!

Answer (score 6):

You need to be more specific when using alternation using the pipe (`|`). You can use the following regex:

```
/([a-f\d]{3,})(?:\?|$)/i
```

`([a-f\d]{3,})` matches the required hexadecimal string. It also makes sure the string is at least 3 characters long. You can adjust this as per your requirements, or just change the quantifier to `+` if you don't mind single-digit strings like `0` being captured.

Note the parentheses around the alternation: `(?:\?|$)` — it specifies that it should match either a `?` **or** the end of the string. `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

With your previous regex, it would mean: match either `.*\/.*-(.*)\?` **or** the end of the string, which is not what you want.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iG0eC0/1)